# How to validate enumerated types in JSON

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following JSON schema:

```
{  
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Ingredients": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "ProductType": {
              "enum": [
                "Cheese",
                "Salad",
                "Condiment"
              ],
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Description",                        
            "ProductType"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And the following JSON snippet:

```
{
  "Ingredients": [
    {
      "Description": "Cheddar",
      "ProductType": "Cheese"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Rocket",
      "ProductType": "Salad"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Onion Relish",
      "ProductType": "Condiment"
    },
    {
      "Description": "Parma Ham",
      "ProductType": "SlicedMeat"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd have expected the validation to fail here since "SlicedMeat" isn't a validation enum.

Any idea how I need to define this in the schema?

I'm using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ is that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with your schema.

If you look at the following site: https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html.

You see at the header: "Going deeper with properties"

That a array is defined like:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"
  }
}
```

So if you change your schema to the following: (edit the type array definition), you should get the expected behavior

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "Product",
  "description": "A product from Acme's catalog",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Ingredients": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "Description": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "ProductType": {
              "type": "string",
              "enum": [
                "Cheese",
                "Salad",
                "Condiment"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "Description",
            "ProductType"
          ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In draft 2019-09 and previous, `items` may be an array or a schema object.

When it's an array, each of the items in that array (which are schema objects), they are applied sequentially to the applicable array.

You're looking for the single schema version of `items`.

This is a common confusion, and we've simplified it for draft `2020-NN`, which is still in the works.

Source: http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.9.3.1.1

> If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the
> array successfully validate against that schema.
>
> If "items" is an array of schemas, validation succeeds if each element
> of the instance validates against the schema at the same position, if
> any.